# Any way to speed up this Magento code?

Tags: php, magento

Is there any way to speed up this Magento code?  Currently it is looking through about 2k products and takes approximately 20 minutes to run.

I'm guessing the issue is around the product->load() call, but I'm not familiar enough Magento to know the overhead it takes.

Thank you.

## from controller

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
    'category_rule_save',
    array(
        'rule_id'        => $id,
        'attribute_code' => $data['attribute_code'],
        'operator'       => $data['operator'],
        'value'          => $data['value'],
        'category_id'    => $data['category'],
        'store_id'       => $data['store_id']
    )
);
```

## from Observer.php

```
public function onCategoryRuleSave($observe)
{
    $collection =
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect($observe['attribute_code']);
    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $product = $product->load($productId);
        $productAttributeValue = '';
        $productAttributeValue =
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)
                ->getAttributeText( $observe['attribute_code'] );
        $r = 0;

        if ( is_numeric($observe['value']) ) {
            switch($observe['operator']) {
                case "<":
                    $r = ($productAttributeValue < $observe['value']) ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
                case ">":
                    $r = ($productAttributeValue > $observe['value']) ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
                case "<=":
                    $r = ($productAttributeValue <= $observe['value']) ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
                case ">=":
                    $r = ($productAttributeValue >= $observe['value']) ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
                case "==":
                    $r = ($productAttributeValue == $observe['value']) ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
                case "!=":
                    $r = ($productAttributeValue != $observe['value']) ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            switch($observe['operator']) {
                case "==":
                    $r = (
                        strcmp(strtolower($productAttributeValue) , strtolower($observe['value'])) == 0
                    ) ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
                case "!=":
                    $r = (
                        strtolower($productAttributeValue) != strtolower($observe['value'])
                    ) ? 1 : 0;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ($r==1) {
            $write->query(
                "REPLACE INTO `catalog_category_product` (`category_id`, `product_id`)
                VALUES (" . $observe['category_id'] . "," . $product->getId() . ")"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the product loading with:

```
...
foreach ($collection as $product) {
 $productAttributeValue = $product->getAttributeText( $observe['attribute_code'] );
 $r = 0;
...
```

You're loading a product object 2 extra times.  The $product variable in the foreach already is the loaded product with the attribute that you need to work with.  Loading a $product object with all of its attributes is expensive given Magento's EAV database structure.

Comment: Thank you.  This brought the time from ~20min down to ~5min.

Comment: You'll also notice a big speed difference depending on the hardware that you're running the code on and the optimization of the MySQL install (which is a little outside of the scope of the question).  Feel free to click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: Update.  Removed the extra product->load. This brought the time down to ~5seconds.  Again, thanks a ton!

Comment: For more speed, test setting up an Amazon EC2 server with nginx, redis, and php-fpm. It is proving pretty snappy for us (1500 products, 5k+ sales).

Answer (score 0):

```
1.$collection =
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($observe['attribute_code']);
```

2.Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)
                ->getAttributeText( $observe['attribute_code'] );

3.$product = $product->load($productId);

That is really awful :)

```
$collection =
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');//this string should load all of the product attributes
```

There also were some methods to add product websites, product store and some others.